# Retrieve items from a sharepoint list using javascript

Tags: sharepoint, windows-forms-designer, caml

```
function getCurrentLoginUserDetails() {
   context1 = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   oList = context1.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Employee Annual Leave Records');

   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
   camlQuery.set_viewXml(
      '<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' +
      '<Value Type=\'Text\'>L</Value></Contains></Where>' +
      '</Query></View>');

   var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
   context1.load(collListItem);

   context1.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceededD,onQueryFailedD);
}


function onQuerySucceededD(sender , args) {
   var listItemInfo = '';
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
       var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
       listItemInfo += '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_title() +
           '\nEmployee Number: ' + oListItem.get_item('Employee_x0020_Number') +
           '\nEmployed Date: ' + oListItem.get_item('Employed_x0020_Date');       
   }
   alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}


function onQueryFailedD(sender , args) {
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I want to retrieve list items from a list name: Employee Annual Leave Records.

My code doesn't show me error.

But my onQuerySucceededD function alert do not show up.

I refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx). I not really understand it, hope somebody can explain to me??

I am wondering what is the problems.

Comment: try to define `var collListItem` globally not within the function

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:-

```
var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

with:-

```
collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

and define `collListItem` globally like this:-

```
<script>
var collListItem;
</script>
```